# change x-axis display in ggplot from individual days to months

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualize a time series for Corona infection rates with three different y columns from a dataset in ggplot with the dates as x-axis. 
Below is an excerpt from my dataset:

```
Nr. Country.Region      cases   recov.  active  deaths
69  Germany 2020-03-30  66885   13500   53385   645
70  Germany 2020-03-31  71808   16100   55708   775
71  Germany 2020-04-01  77872   18700   59172   920
72  Germany 2020-04-02  84794   22440   62354   1107
73  Germany 2020-04-03  91159   24575   66584   1275
74  Germany 2020-04-04  96092   26400   69692   1444
75  Germany 2020-04-05  100123  28700   71423   1584
76  Germany 2020-04-06  103374  28700   74674   1810
77  Germany 2020-04-07  107663  36081   71582   2016
78  Germany 2020-04-08  113296  46300   66996   2349
79  Germany 2020-04-09  118181  52407   65774   2607
80  Germany 2020-04-10  122171  53913   68258   2767
81  Germany 2020-04-11  124908  57400   67508   2736
82  Germany 2020-04-12  127854  60300   67554   3022
83  Germany 2020-04-13  130072  64300   65772   3194
84  Germany 2020-04-14  131359  68200   63159   3294
85  Germany 2020-04-15  134753  72600   62153   3804
86  Germany 2020-04-16  137698  77000   60698   4052
87  Germany 2020-04-17  141397  83114   58283   4352
```

The data I am analyzing spans several months, so when I visualize the data in ggplot with

```
ggplot(cases.Germany) + geom_point(aes(x = date, y = active.cases, col = "active cases")) + labs(title = "Corona cases in Germany", x = "date", y = "No. of incidents") + geom_point(aes(x = date, y = confirmed.cases, col= "confirmed cases")) + geom_point(aes(x = date, y = recovered, col = "recovered"))
```

, I of course get the result shown below: 
[image: CV_Germany]

Now, if possible I want to group the individual days into months that can be used to create an x-axis for my ggplot, but I am quite at a loss on how to do that. 
Thank you for your help and your guidance!

Comment: try adding `+ scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 months")`. Note: x -axis should be date only.

Comment: What do you mean by "group the individual days into months": Monthly  text on the x axis or monthly data, i.e. the sum of cases for each month?

Comment: @Neel thanks! But I am having the issue that it does not accept the code as my "date" colums appears to not be in date format. Do you know how I would transform that column?

Comment: @Peter I want to display the value for each individual day, but want the x-axis to only display the text for each individual month

Comment: OK so the answer is correct, it also includes the call to `dplyr::mutate` to transfor character dates into date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph is a bit limited due to the small range of data provided in the question but it should do the trick; I've assumed when you say group the days into months you are meaning that the labels should display the month?

It would require a different approach if you mean group all the data as monthly data, i.e. the sum of cases for April etc...

I've put the data into long format to simplify the call to ggplot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df1 <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(country, date))

ggplot(df1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = value, col = name)) +
  labs(title = "Corona cases in Germany", x = "date", y = "No. of incidents") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%B")
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame( country = c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany",
                              "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany"),
                  date = c("2020-03-30","2020-03-31", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-02", "2020-04-03", "2020-04-04",
                           "2020-04-05", "2020-04-06", "2020-04-07", "2020-04-08", "2020-04-09", 
                           "2020-04-10", "2020-04-11", "2020-04-12", "2020-04-13", "2020-04-14", 
                           "2020-04-15", "2020-04-16", "2020-04-17"),
                  cases = c(66885L, 71808L, 77872L, 84794L, 91159L, 96092L, 100123L, 103374L, 107663L, 113296L, 118181L, 122171L, 124908L, 127854L, 130072L, 131359L, 134753L, 137698L, 141397L), 
                  recov = c(13500L, 16100L, 18700L, 22440L, 24575L, 26400L, 28700L, 28700L, 36081L, 46300L, 52407L, 53913L, 57400L, 60300L, 64300L, 68200L, 72600L, 77000L, 83114L),
                  active = c(53385L, 55708L, 59172L, 62354L, 66584L, 69692L, 71423L, 74674L, 71582L, 66996L, 65774L, 68258L, 67508L, 67554L, 65772L, 63159L, 62153L, 60698L, 58283L), 
                  deaths = c(645L, 775L, 920L, 1107L, 1275L, 1444L, 1584L, 1810L, 2016L, 2349L, 2607L, 2767L, 2736L, 3022L, 3194L, 3294L, 3804L, 4052L, 4352L))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hey, I suddenly get an error "Columns 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 7 more must be named." when trying to execute ```df1 <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(country, date))```
Is this a problem with the new R 4.0 version or could I have messed something else up?

Comment: Are you using the sample data in the question? This data works fine on my maching, I've just copied the data and code from the question. Are you perhaps referring to another data frame in your code?

Comment: Okay, so I am apparently an idiot, sorry. Your code works fine, I simply had not loaded "reshape2" before I ran the code, I had done so in earlier sessions for another project and apparently carried it over, I went over it line by line again and found my mistake. Sorry but thank you again for your help! :)

Comment: Don't worry about it I find that 70% or more errors are due to typos or missing something obvious!